Feature engineering highly corrrelated features
I am creating a classification model for predicting ER visits for patients. The target variable is whether a patient has visited the ER or not, 0 if no visits and 1 if they have visited at least once. One of the features is the number of times the patient has visited the ER in the past. This feature is highly correlated with the target, because a non-zero value corresponds with 1 in the target and a 0 corresponds to a 0 in the target, and hence I had to remove it.
But, this could be very useful information, because, greater the number of times a patient has visited the ER, the higher the probability they will visit again. I tried many ways to engineer the feature like converting to a categorical variable, binning it, but even then the correlation was still very high.
Is there a way to engineer this feature so that it can be used too?

Why do you think you need to remove this feature? As you write, it is highly predictive.

I second this confusion. It seems like you have a perfect predictor of the outcome, which would be a dream come true.

Personal level predictions for ER may not be that actionable. Try to pool patients into meaningful buckets over-time as a visit-volume. See Predicting daily emergency department visits using machine learning could increase accuracy.

You say you want to predict an ER visit, but your target variable is if they have visited (past tense); that is contradictory? And then "feature" (independent variable) you are asking about is the number of past visits? Please edit the question to clarify it; as it stands your statements are contradictory

@StephanKolassa It sounds like the response/target is exactly the same as the predictor, just turned into a binary.

@SureshSubramaniam Am I correct about this? If not, could you describe the data in more detail? Including it as a predictor should be fine if the variables are separated in time, at least. For e.g., if you use the number of ER visits before 2010 to predict the probability of visiting the ER after 2010.
